# reserve,used,available,total disk space in linux

Tags: linux, system-calls, diskspace, linux-disk-free

Is there any single linux command or single system call through which I can get all 4 information(Total,used,free,reserved) ?

I have checked following:

```
df: does not give reserve disk space
stat(): does not give reserve disk space
statfs(): gives total and free only
```

I tried using "tune2fs -l /dev/vda1" for reserved ,but there is some discrepancy between outputs of tune2fs and df command.The total is not coming as sum of used,free and reserved.

Comment: Might be available in the `/proc` or `/sys` file-systems?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: have you tried using vmstat -s ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi sorry..it is not programming or dev question,is it possible to port directly to stack exchange or need to close this and raise a new question there.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer vmstat -s is not giving reserved disk space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a calculation with df output :

> reserved=total-used-free